# Why didn't Dr. Ana Stelline reveal this?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049* why did Doctor Ana Stelline not reveal to K that it was actually her memory implanted on him?

Answer (score 2):

Because implanting real memories of existing person is against the law and K is a police officer.